# handling of `--` in minted

Tags: luatex, fontspec, minted

I'm using `minted` for pretty printing console output and have just noticed that double hyphens, i.e. `--`, for program options are getting turned in en-hyphens, i.e. `–`.  A MWE is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmonofont{Courier}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{bash}
0-1--2---3
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

and I see:

[image: lualatex output]

rather than what I'd hope for, a number of individual hyphens.

While making the MWE, I've realised that it's probably to do with an interaction with the `fontspec` option `Ligatures=TeX`, but I can't find a reliable way to selectively disable the option—I can do it inside XeLaTeX, but not luaLaTeX.  Is it best just to ensure the mono font is loaded without `Ligatures=TeX`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conjecture is true:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% disable the default 'Ligatures=TeX' option
\defaultfontfeatures{}
\setmonofont{Courier}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{bash}
0-1--2---3
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have ligatures in running text also for the monospaced font, but not in `minted`, use a new font family. A small hack is necessary for retrieving the correct font family name.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmonofont{Courier}[Ligatures=TeX]

\defaultfontfeatures{}
\newfontfamily\noligsmonofamily[NFSSFamily=noligsmonofamily]{Courier}

\setminted{fontfamily=noligsmonofamily}

\begin{document}

This---has---ligatures

\texttt{This---has---ligatures}

\begin{minted}{bash}
0-1--2---3
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know it's true.  I really wanted to be able to have `Ligatures=TeX` everywhere for compatibility.

Comment: @SamMason Just issue `\defaultfontfeatures{}` before defining `\setmonofont`; the fonts already loaded will respect the `\defaultfontfeatures` options in force at definition time; the option `Ligatures=TeX` is implicit at startup, with the most recent version of `fontspec`.

Comment: I was hoping I could have the option on most of the time and just have it disabled selectively within `minted` blocks.  Maybe I should just create a version of the mono font with TeX ligatures off and just have `minted` specifically use it?

Comment: @SamMason That would indeed be the best choice. I'll add some code later.

Comment: @SamMason Solution on line

Comment: wow, that's a bit more fiddly than I expected, but thanks!

Comment: @SamMason I wish `fontspec` provided a hook for the allocated family name after doing `\newfontfamily`. Unfortunately, `fancyvrb` (which manages the key `fontfamily`) only accepts an explicit family name as value, so a hypothetical `fontfamily=\noligsmono` would issue errors.

Comment: I've just had a play, and seen you can do:  `\newfontfamily\mintedfont{Courier}[NFSSFamily=mintedfamily]
\setminted{fontfamily=mintedfamily}`

Comment: @SamMason Interesting; although it's the reverse of what I did.