# How to unset default Ligatures=TeX for main font? (TexLive2015)

Tags: luatex, fontspec, ligatures

As of TexLive2015 (as opposed to TexLive2013) fontspec predefines `Ligatures=TeX`. This results in double quotes being replaced by curly quotes. How can I disable this behavior?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
force "x y Fx Fy"
\end{document}
```

[image: curly quotes not wanted]

In comment to the question [handling of `--` in minted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250771/handling-of-in-minted/250777#comment597486_250777) egreg mentioned using `\defaultfontfeatures{}` before defining the font, but in the case above it has no effect.
There is the *selnolig* package ([Any suggestions/requests for features for a new package that allows disabling ligatures for (pre)selected words?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37443/any-suggestions-requests-for-features-for-a-new-package-that-allows-disabling-li)), but I haven't found a command to disable TeX-"ligatures".

The work-around I've found was to edit the file '/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg', deleting the line `{Ligatures=TeX}`. I'd prefer a solution that avoids touching the installation.

Is there any `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=NoTeX}`?

Comment: Welcome! Even if you did need to alter the `.cfg` file, ***you ought not change that one***. You ought not modify stuff in the main TEXMF tree because, other considerations aside, it will simply be liable to erasure when you update the installation.

Comment: I suppose one could use the [selnolig package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/selnolig) to disable `--` (en-dash) and `---` (em-dash) "ligatures". (It would seem overkill, though, to use the package for this purpose.) However, AFAICT the package can not be used to keep TeX from converting "straight" (single and double) quote characters to equivalent "smart" quote characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 6.1 of the manual tells how to set the features for specified families declared with `\setmainfont` or `\setsansfont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily,\ttfamily]{}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

force "x y Fx Fy"

-- ---

`` ''
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To disable TeX-type ligatures, you could pass the option `RawFeature=-tlig` to the instructions `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont`, etc. (`tlig` is short for "TeX-style ligatures"; `-tlig` disables the "tlig" font feature.) No need to do this for `\setmonofont` as TeX-style ligatures aren't enabled by default for monospaced fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[RawFeature=-tlig]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[RawFeature=-tlig]{Calibri}

\begin{document}
" `` -- ---

\textsf{" `` -- ---}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will only work in LuaLaTeX btw

Comment: @WillRobertson - In a broader sense, it's unfortunate that that the `fontspec` package currently permits setting `Ligatures=TeX` but doesn't permit setting `Ligatures=NoTeX`. This asymmetry is surprising, given that the pairs `Common`/`NoCommon` and `Rare`/`NoRare` work fine for enabling and disabling certain ligatures.

Comment: Good point! I don't know whether that's possible in XeTeX at the moment but I'll investigate: https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/221

Answer (score 1):

If you just wish to disable the curly quotes "sometimes," then you can do the following (works with LuaLaTeX, fontspec; I don't know about XeTeX):

```
\defaultfontfeatures{} % complete removel
\def\straightquote{{\addfontfeature{Ligatures=ResetAll}'}}
\def\straightdblquote{{\addfontfeature{Ligatures=ResetAll}"}}
```

Be sure to do that after you have defined all other fonts, so that removing all default font features does not propagate to later-defined fonts.

Then, in the body of your document, use `\straightquote` and `\straightdblquote` as needed. You will need to follow the usual TeX rule about following a macro with a space or {} to be gobbled.